# Combine specific index of vector with another index element in the same vector using R

Tags: r, element

Vector includes this file

```
c("Car", "Bus", "Subway", "Truck", "Speed", "Car")
```

I would like to take "Speed" and unite it with "Car"

My outcome should be

```
c("Car", "Bus", "Subway", "Truck", "Speed Car")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new vector with length one less than the original vector and `paste`

```
v2 <- v1[seq_len(length(v1)-1)]
v2[length(v2)] <- paste(v1[5:6], collapse = " ")
```

-output

```
> v2
[1] "Car"       "Bus"       "Subway"    "Truck"     "Speed Car"
```

---

Or in a single line

```
> c(v1[1:4], paste(v1[5:6], collapse = " "))
[1] "Car"       "Bus"       "Subway"    "Truck"     "Speed Car"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("Car", "Bus", "Subway", "Truck", "Speed", "Car")
```